# IE sends ? character instead of Unicode characters in HTTP GET

Tags: browser, unicode, internet-explorer-9

I've created a web form for search operation in one of my projects, and the HTML is pretty simple:

```
<form action='/search' method="post">
    <input type="text" id='search-term' name='search-term' />
    <input type="submit" id='start-search' alt='' value="" />
</form>
```

So, when user types Unicode search term and hits Enter, an HTTP Get request would be sent to the server with this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/search?search-term=مثال
```

This, in server would be:

```
http://www.example.com/search?search-term=%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84
```

and I'm able to retrieve the decoded value of the `search-term` query string using `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode("%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84")` which returns `مثال` to me. Till here everything works fine and I have no problem.

However, if somebody type the aforementioned address directly in IE9, and hit Enter, then what I get at server is:

```
http://www.example.com/search?search-term=????
```

What's wrong here?

Update: We checked the traffic via Fiddler, and you can see the result in following pictures:

HTTP Get headers, captured by Fiddler, requested with Firefox
[image: HTTP Get headers, captured by Fiddler]

HTTP Get headers, captured by Fiddler, requested with IE
[image: HTTP Get headers, captured by Fiddler]

Comment: Mixing single- and double-quotes in HTML... why so sloppy?

Comment: No @MattBall, this is what I wrote here. But you're right. A single approach works better. Viva consistency!

Comment: Who says it's IE9? Have you used Fiddler or something to capture what IE is sending, maybe your server doesn't understand the request.

Comment: I used Firebug to see what IE is sending, and in Firebug, everything is OK. But in server (at the very starting point or context_BeginRequest) characters are just like `????`.

Comment: Okay well your question should be "HTTP Server and Unicode Characters"

Comment: But we only have this problem with IE9.

Comment: @Todda.speot.is, we used Fiddler (not Firebug this time, and not IE developer tools), and what we saw, was that the HTTP GET was sent to the server like `????`. So, no server fault. Nothing related to server. It's only IE problem (or client's problem in general).

Answer (score 5):

IE does not know what charset you want to use when typing the URL manually, so it has to use a default charset. `?` characters occur when Unicode characters are converted to an Ansi charset that does not support those Unicode characters.  When submitting a webform instead, IE uses the charset of the webform, which can be specified by the `<form>` tag itself, in `<meta>` tags within the HTML document, or the HTTP `Content-Type` header, so there is less chance that IE has to guess the correct charset to use.